# Find the last empty cell and complete it with a function

Tags: vba, excel

i did a program to list the path of files in 'fld' folder in an excel sheet , but i do not know how to search each time for the last line and complete it with the function of listing files .
Then to add just the new files and keep the older .
this is the vba :

```
    Sub test()
  Dim fso As FileSystemObject
  Dim oSourceFolder As Scripting.Folder
  Dim oSubFolder As Scripting.Folder
  Dim oFile As Scripting.File
  Dim oFolder As Scripting.Folder
  Dim strFolderName As String
  Dim i As Long
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Cells(1, 1).Value = "fld"   
   strFolderName= "C:\Users\fld"

    i = 2      
    Range("A2").Select
    ActiveCell = Range("A2")   
  Set oSourceFolder = fso.GetFolder(strFolderName)
  For Each oFolder In oSourceFolder.SubFolders
            For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
            Cells(i, 1).Value = Left(oFile.ParentFolder)                
                         i = i + 1
            Next oFile
    Next oFolder
```

the excel sheet is :

```
C:\Users\fld\file1  
C:\Users\fld\file2  
C:\Users\fld\file3
```

This program repeat it self each time , and it rewrite the path on the excel sheet . Otherwise , i want to just search the last line and write the path folder that is just added.

for exampls if i add C:\Users\fld\file4 , it will be added automaticly to the end of the cell .

Comment: Can you give an example of the outcome you would like?

Comment: @JordanBiddlecombe i added an example

Answer (score 1):

Quicker way of doing this without looping:

```
Sub ListFiles()

Dim files As Variant

files = Filter(Split(CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Exec("CMD /C DIR ""C:\Users\fld\*.*"" /S /B /A:-D").StdOut.ReadAll, vbCrLf), vbCrLf), ".")

Range("A2").Resize(UBound(files) + 1).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(files)

End Sub
```

You might see a command prompt (black box) show up for a couple of seconds, which is normal. It's using the DIR command in CMD.exe to get the file listing from all subfolders, parsing the output into an array, and then transposing the array directly into the worksheet.

Comment: Thank you for your answer , but this line won't work : Range("A2").Resize(UBound(files) + 1).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(files)

Comment: the excel sheet is empty , it didn't take any of those paths , and they show me :
Incompatible file type

Comment: Is this: `C:\Users\fld\ ` the actual folder you're searching? If not, did you change it to your real folder?

Comment: So that whole line should be `"CMD /C DIR ""P:\Desktop\Name\Imported\*.*"" /S /B /A:-D"` Is that what you've got?

Comment: Yes that what i did . nut always the incompatible type problem